# Find currently connected port number SSH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

i'm creating a local simulator (not connected to internet) using SSH connection. I've started sshd on a particular range of port numbers and NATing a range of devices to those. I have to find the currently connected port number.

OS CentOS 5.5
OpenSSH 6.1

I've done the following. It works for normal usage (manual user).But when trying a rigorous testing(automated) it seems like it is failing sometimes to find the port number.

```
#!/bin/bash

WHOINFO=`who -m`

USERNAME=`echo $WHOINFO | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'`
PTSNUMBER=`echo $WHOINFO | awk 'NR==1{print $2}'`

USERSTR=$USERNAME"@"$PTSNUMBER

PID=`ps -eLf | grep $USERSTR | awk 'NR==1{print $3}'`

if [ -z "$PID" ];
then
        exit
fi

PORTSTR=`netstat -natp | grep $PID | awk 'NR==1{print $4}'`

PORTNUMBER=${PORTSTR//*:/}

echo $PORTNUMBER
```

Comment: your grep pattern for PID should be `$PID/`, as it is presented in that form in the output; otherwise you may incorrectly match ports that are numbered the same as the `PID` you're trying to match.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An OpenSSH server will set the variable `$SSH_CLIENT`, which contains the current ip, client port and server port separated by spaces:

```
$ echo "$SSH_CLIENT"
127.0.0.1 59064 22
```

To get the port number the current session is connected to, you can therefore use `echo ${SSH_CLIENT##* }`.

Comment: and if he wants to he can read that environment variable from the `/proc/<pid>/environ` file by piping it through `tr '\0' '\n'`

Comment: @that other guy Brilliant! my entire script now got reduced to an echo command. I couldn't find this variable. Thnx.